# BASH - how to retrieve all names from one directory?

Tags: bash

How to retrieve **all** names from **one** directory?

The directory contains names such as :

```
.foo bar
.10
10.foo bar
foo bar.foo bar
```

I tried

```
for item in $(ls "/opt/$PATH")
do
    echo "$item"
done
```

Will anyone advise? Thank you.

Comment: See also [Why you don't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), and [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't parse the output of `ls`. Use globs, for example:

```
for item in "/opt/$path"/*; do echo "$item"; done
```

If you want just the filename without absolutely path, you have several options, for example:

```
for item in "/opt/$path"/*; do basename "$item"; done
```

or:

```
(cd "/opt/$path" && for item in *; do echo "$item"; done)
```

If you want to include hidden files too, you can set `dotglob` option before the above commands:

```
shopt -s dotglob
```

---

As a side note, the use of `"/opt/$PATH"` is extremely suspicious.
`PATH` is an extremely important variable in the shell, containing a colon-separated list of directories in which the shell looks for commands.
It's unlikely that `"/opt/$PATH"` will have the effect that you want.
Do not use this variable for other purposes than it's designed.